# VM out of Gas Exception trying to call a function belonging to an other contract

Tags: solidity

I am trying to call a function from a different contract but keep running into an VM out of gas exception.

I am using the IDE offered by Oraclize to test the following code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;

contract ContractA {
    ContractB contractB;

    constructor() public {
        contractB = new ContractB();
    }

    function saySomething() external returns(string) {
        return contractB.retunsAString();
    }
}

contract ContractB {
    function retunsAString() public pure returns(string) {
        return "Hello to you all!";
    }
}
```

If I try to make the function saySomething() a view this error happens while compiling.

I tried searching before asking but could not found a post that explained it (at least not in a way I understand).

Why is this happening and is there any way to solve it so the code does as I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine (just add `view` in saySomething function).
So, first, go to official IDE from Ethereum - http://remix.ethereum.org.

Top right go to `Run` tab, then choose: environment - JavaScript VM (if you have metamask - injected web3). Paste this code and press `deploy`

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;

contract ContractA {
    ContractB contractB;

    constructor() public {
        contractB = new ContractB();
    }

    function saySomething() external view returns(string memory) {
        return contractB.retunsAString();
    }
}

contract ContractB {
    function retunsAString() public pure returns(string memory) {
        return "Hello to you all!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just as an extra note to those that might read this. It all seems to behave a bit differently depending on the IDE you are using. Remix gives a clear warning about the saySomething (can be declared as a view) function, but the Oraclize IDE seems to think it needs to throw an out of gas exception.